# I need to know where I'm wrong in json object to POST using TIdHTTP in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, post, indy, idhttp

source gives socket error 14001, WITH OBJ JSON PARAM MESSAGE FOR POST

```
jso := TlkJSONobject.Create; // (data) as TlkJSONobject;   

jso.Add('InvoiceNumber', '');
jso.Add('POSID', '910441');
jso.add('USIN', ePOSNo.Text);
jso.add('DATETIME', eDate.Text);

IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

{ Call the Post method of TIdHTTP and read the result into TMemo }
Memo1.Lines.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost;8524/api/IMSFISCAL/GetInvoiceNumberByModel', JSO);
```

json cannot be passed as tstream

need help on it

Answer (score 3):

There is no way the code you showed can produce a socket error (let alone error 14001, which is not even a socket error) since the code won't even compile!

The `TIdHTTP.Post()` method does not have an overload that accepts a `TlkJSONobject` as input. How could it? `TlkJSONobject` comes from a completely different 3rd party library, it is not part of the RTL or Indy. The only things you can `POST` with `TIdHTTP` are:

- `TStrings`-derived types
- `TStream`-derived types, including Indy's `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`
- a file specified by a `String` filename

In this case, you need to use a `TStream` to post JSON stored in memory. It is your responsibility to save your `TlkJSONobject` content to a suitable `TStream` of your choosing. That is outside the scope of Indy. For instance, you can use `TlkJSON.GenerateText()` to get the JSON into a `String`  and then `POST` it using a `TStringStream`.

On a side note, the URL you are passing to `TIdHTTP.Post()` is malformed. The correct delimiter between a hostname and port number is a colon (`:`), not a semicolon (`;`).

With that said, try this:

```pascal
jso := TlkJSONobject.Create;

jso.Add('InvoiceNumber', '');
jso.Add('POSID', '910441');
jso.add('USIN', ePOSNo.Text);
jso.add('DATETIME', eDate.Text);

IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

{ Call the Post method of TIdHTTP and read the result into TMemo }
PostData := TStringStream.Create(TlkJSON.GenerateText(jso), TEncoding.UTF8);
try
  Memo1.Lines.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost:8524/api/IMSFISCAL/GetInvoiceNumberByModel', PostData);
finally
  PostData.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I'll remember this answer for my future work. +1), thanks.

Comment: :i m gettting error #10061 now with connection refused

Comment: @Hamza did you fix the malformed URL like I described? If so, then the error means you likely do not have an HTTP server running on `localhost` (127.0.0.1) on port 8524

Comment: jso: TlkJSONobject;
  PostData:  TstringStream;begin     jso := TlkJSONobject.Create;

jso.Add('InvoiceNumber', '');
jso.Add('POSID', '910441');
jso.add('USIN', ePOSNo.Text);
jso.add('DATETIME', eDate.Text);

IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

{ Call the Post method of TIdHTTP and read the result into TMemo }
    PostData := TStringStream.Create(TlkJSON.GenerateText(jso));
try
  Memo1.Lines.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost:8524/api/IMSFISCAL/GetInvoiceNumberByModel', PostData);
finally
  PostData.Free;
end;

Comment: @Hamza assuming your URL actually starts with `http://` and my browser is not just hiding it, then the code is fine (which version of Delphi are you using?). So again, are you actually running an HTTP server on your local machine, listening on 127.0.0.1 on port 8524?

Comment: iis is running on pc and fiscalservice is running in pc

Comment: its post call to webservice api running on some other system ,https://help.fbr.gov.pk/?p=6148